# Can undergraduate students really post something on arXiv.org?

Tags: research-undergraduate, arxiv

Are there any cases of undergraduate students posting something on arXiv.org? Can undergraduate student (or any arbitrary person) REALLY post to arxiv and if not, then how does the protection work?

In principle, the mechanism of [endorsement](http://arxiv.org/help/endorsement) seems to allow such content to pass through.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Academia.SE! I believe your question is addressed by the linked post, but if it's not, please [edit] to highlight what *isn't* covered in that question. If it's sufficiently different, it can be reopened.

Comment: Thanks for some clarifications. But can you provide any real samples of such papers (written by undergraduates)? Is it possible to search for them automatically?

Comment: [This search query](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+AND+science+AND+bachelor+of/0/1/0/all/0/1) turns up a few undergrad theses and project reports.

Comment: arXiv doesn't have any way of   knowing whether authors are undergraduates or not (that isn't part of the information collected when a paper is submitted) so there won't be a way to directly search for such papers (though ff254 suggests an indirect approach). But you seem to have real doubts that undergraduates can post papers there at all and I don't understand why. Would you like to explain?

Comment: I am debating with some sci freaks and conspiracy advocates, and would like to have more proofs that free investigations are not banned by sci mafia. Something like this :)

Comment: I am an ArXiv moderator. As Nate says, moderators have no way to check whether an author is an undergraduate, a tenured professor, or a janitor, and we don't care.

Comment: Thanks! May I ask more? Are you reading articles? What if student will report some alternative theory, contradicting widely accepted theories, but it will be well developed, like MOND or similar? Will you reject the article just on the base of contradiction? And contrary, what if it article has non-evident mathematical errors, will you allow it?